# How to display the preview of received information (Code correction request)

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

My telegram-bot codes (using NetTelegramBotApi) are as follows, and I need help for the problems mentioned in comments:

- Display the preview of received information to confirm (Ex. Your Address: 74 Green Street. Your Phone Number: 123456 & Your Company Name: MyCo. Please check and confirm that the information are correct.).

UI: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HDMK.png)

```
using NetTelegramBotApi;
using NetTelegramBotApi.Requests;
using NetTelegramBotApi.Types;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace mybot
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ReplyKeyboardMarkup mainMenu;
        private static ReplyKeyboardMarkup confirmMenu;
        private static string botToken = "***";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            mainMenu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
            {
                Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][] {
                    new KeyboardButton[]
                    {
                        new KeyboardButton("Address"),
                        new KeyboardButton("Phone"),
                        new KeyboardButton("Company Name")
                    }
                }
            };
            confirmMenu = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
            {
                Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][] {
                    new KeyboardButton[]
                    {
                        new KeyboardButton("Confirm"),
                        new KeyboardButton("Restart")
                    }
                }
            };
            Task.Run(() => RunBot());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static async Task RunBot()
        {
            var bot = new TelegramBot(botToken);
            var me = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetMe());
            Console.Write("username is {0}", me.Username);
            long offset = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                var updates = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetUpdates() { Offset = offset });
                foreach (var update in updates)
                {
                    offset = update.UpdateId + 1;
                    var text = update.Message.Text;
                    if (text == "/start" || text == "Restart")
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Please use the Menu") { ReplyMarkup = mainMenu };
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (text == "Address")
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Please enter your address:");
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (text == "Phone")
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Please enter your phone number:");
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else if (text == "Company Name")
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Please enter your company name:");
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        /* Now, I need to show him the preview of received information to confirm. 
                        Example:
                        Your Address: ***
                        Your Phone Number: ***
                        & Your Company Name: ***
                        Please check and confirm that the information are correct ('confirmMenu' keyboard could be used).
                        */
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var req = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "Error! Please follow the instructions") { ReplyMarkup = mainMenu };
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(req);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for phone number and location you can add optional values to your keyboardbutton, so that user can send his/her number/location by pressing that button:

<"request_contact" : true> for phone number and <"request_location": true> for location.

for confirmation:after receiving user's info, show him/her the received info with [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#inlinekeyboardbutton) containing 2 yes/no buttons.